# Chrome Extension Content Script Not Firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working  on a simple chrome extension to see how they're done, and I've followed tutorials but still can't get it working properly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Extension</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="step-1-test-extension flex-container active">
            <div class="step-number">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="step-explanation">
                <p>Go to Link Test.</p>
            </div>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" id="test-button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="button">Visit Facebook</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
window.onload = () => {
    let testButton = document.getElementById('test-button');
    testButton.innerText = 'test';
    testButton.addEventListener('click', console.log('test click'));

    console.log('Chrome extension go');
}
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "description": "Quick Test Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["test.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"]
    }]
}
```

Nothing in the test.js is working properly. It's not console.logging anything and no action is taken when I click the button, so the addEventListener isn't working either. I've reloaded the extension, it's properly set to dev mode and it's appearing on my browser bar with the popup working, but none of the content script is working?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the `popup.html` and the `test.js` files located?

Comment: They're in the extension. The test.js is in the same folder as the popup.html, it's not in a subdirectory/folder or anything.

Comment: Open the popup and right click on anything inside and open the devtools, do you see any errors?

Comment: Oh it's working in the popup's console but not the page that I'm trying to view (facebook.com)?? Like is it possible to make the console.log appear on the page I'm on? Cause the function I need to run needs to run on that page, not the console of the popup?

Comment: The script in your `popup.html` will only run in the context of the popup, if you need something to happen in the page, the content script is what you want, and you can communicate between them using [`messages`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

Comment: The script I'm using to listen to the event listener for the button clicks inside the popup is already inside the content_script for the function that needs to be called. It's all one file. Once the button is clicked from the eventListener, I need it to call a function that updates the DOM of the activeTab. If that makes sense. Do I still need to use messages for that?

Comment: Yes, because even though the file is the same, the scripts are 2 different scripts in 2 different contexts (one would be living in the popup and another one in the context)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying. Now I've added the send and onMessage event listeners but I'm getting an error stating that it's not a valid endpoint. So I'm gonna have to look into that. Thank you!

Comment: I'll leave an answer with what we've discussed below, so you can mark as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you have one script (`test.js`) that's being referenced both as a **Content Script** and as a script in the **Popup**

The script in the `popup.html` will **only run in the context of the popup**

The content script, however, will **only run in the actual page**

---

You can communicate between them using [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage), which I believe is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks kinda plain and funny... can you do that these days?

```
testButton.addEventListener('click', console.log('test click'));
```

Shouldn't it be more like...

```
 testButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){

  console.log('test click');

 },true); // <-- should it bubble?
```

Also, should you be using an expensive event listener when you could just...

```
testButton.onclick=function(e){console.log('test click');};
```

Eh?